# Save matrix to .txt

Tags: matlab

I want to save a matrix file to "`.txt` ". BUT when I saved the file with `fprintf` code the text file save as text not a matrix.

The code I used is

```
fid1=fopen('surf_tran_accn_198601161.txt','w');
fprintf(fid1,'%d %f %10.5d',e87');
```

Comment: What do you mean "save as text and not a matrix"?  You're saving to a text file.... so of course it's going to be text.  What exactly do you want to do?  Do you want to save the matrix to file as text? I wouldn't use `fprintf` for that.  I would use `dlmwrite`.

Comment: I want to write matrix in text as numericaly.

Comment: but fprintf save that as wirtten.

Comment: tanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the matrix into an ascii file and preserve the row/column formatting (i.e. so that it looks like a matrix), you can just use the save command:

```
g = eye(15)
save('m.txt','g','-ascii')
```

you can also use the '-double' flag if you need more digits of precision. To load it back into the workspace as a matrix, you can just use the load command:

```
gg = load('m.txt')
```